# Why would arsort() make a central value as the first?

Tags: php, arrays

While learning PHP at teamtreehouse.com I came across this question:

```
$colors = array("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Black");
```

> Which function will sort the array so the first element is "Yellow"?

The answer to the question is `arsort()`, but I can't understand why, because the [PHP man](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) says:

> arsort — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

I understand from the man that `arsort()` will just reverse the order, so that `Black` will become first instead of last, but then, why does the Treehouse question answer says Yellow will be first?

Might it be a authors mistake in the question? Thanks.

**Note:** I tried to create a headline useful for people with similar confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `asort` and `arsort` sort the input array (alphabetically in this case), it's just a matter of which order then are sorted in.

> [asort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) — Sort an array and maintain index association
>
> [arsort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

So it's not just a simple array reversal like [`array_reverse`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), it sorts them too.

Comment: @Benia Alphabetically, Y comes after all the others.

Comment: I now understand it's due to alphabetical sorting as Y is last before Z, it differs from simple, nonalphabetical sorting as with `array_reverse`.